Getting an error: "Could not unzip uploaded file" when using PublishLayerVersionCommand from @aws-sdk v3 with localstack
I am trying to test am AWS lambda function using localstack. I am attempting to create a layer for the lambda to use but it says it cannot unzip the file I am passing to it. I have followed the documentation to the best of my knowledge and am having trouble finding a solution. Any help would be much appreciated!
Simplified code:
import archiver from 'archiver';
import fs from 'fs;
import { LambdaClient, PublishLayerVersionCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda';

describe('test example', () => {
  it('creates a layer', async () => {
    const layerName = 'myLayerName';
    const awsConfig = {
      region: 'us-south-1',
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
        secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
      },
    };
    const lambdaClient = new LambdaClient(awsConfig);
    const rootDir = process.cwd();
    const outputPath = `${rootDir}/output.zip`;
    const layerOutput = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
    const layerArchiver = createArchiver('zip');

    layerArchiver.pipe(layerOutput);
    layerArchiver.directory(`${rootDir}/node_modules`, false);

    await layerArchiver.finalize();

    await lambdaClient.send(
      new PublishLayerVersionCommand({
        Content: { ZipFile: fs.readFileSync(outputPath) },
        LayerName: layerName,
      })
    );
  });
});

I have seen other questions advising that the ZipFile needs to be a buffer, but as you can see, that is not the problem I am encountering. The generated zipFile is 14.7MB and I am able to unzip it and see all the files as expected.
My only guess is that maybe localstack has a very low file size requirement and I am exceeding the limit. Hopefully someone can point out where I am going wrong or let me know if my guess is correct as I have not been able to find anything in the documentation regarding this issue.
I am using

yarn v1.22.22 to install dependencies.
@aws-sdk version: 3.699.0
archiver version: 7.0.1
node version: 22.11.0
localstack is running via docker and is the "latest" image

The error I am receiving (which is not very helpful):

InvalidParameterValueException: Could not unzip uploaded file. Please
check your file, then try to upload again.

-- update
After looking into the possibility that it is a size issue, I have found that this should not be the case. Looking at documentation for the environment variables that can be set for localstack, and explicitly setting LAMBDA_LIMITS_CODE_SIZE_ZIPPED and LAMBDA_LIMITS_CREATE_FUNCTION_REQUEST_SIZE to values larger than I am working with, the failure still occurs.

I was able to resolve the issue, the two things I did to resolve the problem were:
add a compression level to archiver
const layerArchiver = archiver({
    zlib: { level: 9 }
});

and wait for the close event on the writeStream
const outputPath = `${rootDir}/output.zip`;
const layerOutput = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
const layerArchiver = createArchiver('zip');

layerArchiver.pipe(layerOutput);
layerArchiver.directory(`${rootDir}/node_modules`, false);

await layerArchiver.finalize();
await new Promise(resolve => {
  layerOutput.on('close', resolve);
});

I think the second modification was the main one, it ensures all files have been processed before uploading them in the lambda function.
final code looks like:
import archiver from 'archiver';
import fs from 'fs;
import { LambdaClient, PublishLayerVersionCommand } from '@aws-sdk/client-lambda';

describe('test example', () => {
  it('creates a layer', async () => {
    const layerName = 'myLayerName';
    const awsConfig = {
      region: 'us-south-1',
      credentials: {
        accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
        secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
      },
    };
    const lambdaClient = new LambdaClient(awsConfig);
    const rootDir = process.cwd();
    const outputPath = `${rootDir}/output.zip`;
    const layerOutput = fs.createWriteStream(outputPath);
    const layerArchiver = createArchiver('zip', {
      zlib: { level: 9 }
    });

    layerArchiver.pipe(layerOutput);
    layerArchiver.directory(`${rootDir}/node_modules`, false);

    await layerArchiver.finalize();

    await new Promise(resolve => {
      layerOutput.on('close', resolve);
    });

    await lambdaClient.send(
      new PublishLayerVersionCommand({
        Content: { ZipFile: fs.readFileSync(outputPath) },
        LayerName: layerName,
      })
    );
  });
});

